# Как проверить, находится ли бот в голосовом канале

Tags: python, python-3.x, бот, discord.py, disnake

Мне нужна проверка, если бот в голосовом канале и музыка при этом не играет, но никак не могу сделать проверку на наличие бота в любом голосовом канале.

Вот несколько примеров кода:

```
@loop(seconds=10)
async def task():
    if bot.user.voice.channel is not None and vc is None:
        await bot.user.edit(voice_channel=None)
```

```
@loop(seconds=10)
async def task():
    if bot.get_guild(1139203298801492029).get_member(1160225516251525221).voice.channel is not None and vc is None:
        await bot.user.edit(voice_channel=None)
```

В первом примере кода ошибка `AttributeError: '_MissingSentinel' object has no attribute 'id'`, ну это понятно. Во втором он не может найти сервер по айди: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_member'`.

Возможно ли как-то проверять находится ли бот в любом из голосовых каналов на любом сервере?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В двух ваших примерах проблемы довольно таки разные.

В первом случае, бот ещё не успел инициализироваться, поэтому вместо `bot.user` будет возвращён объект `_MissingSentinel`, по иному значащийся как None.

Во втором случае, вероятнее всего, у вас не включены Intents для того, чтобы бот мог достать из кэша нужный вам сервер. Вместо `get_guild` можно использовать `fetch_guild`.

Если вы хотите узнать, в каких голосовых каналах находится ваш бот, то в этом вам может помочь `bot.voice_clients`.